# SQL Update doesn't work with Group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to make a table that will count the amount of questions I have and with the right WHERE clause

```
   create table #test(
    BatchNo int,
    Q varchar(MAX),
    number varchar(MAX),
    DayNo varchar(MAX),
    total int 
   )

  INSERT INTO #test ( BatchNo, Q,number, DayNo, total ) VALUES
  ( 2, 'A','1', '1', NULL ),
  ( 2, 'A','1', '1', NULL ),
  ( 8, 'A','3', '1', NULL ),
  ( 8, 'A','3', '1', NULL ),
  ( 99, 'A','4', '1', NULL ),
  ( 200, 'A','3', '1', NULL ),
  ( 200, 'A','3', '1', NULL ),
  ( 200, 'A','3', '1', NULL )
```

I used this UPDATE because for some reason GROUP BY Batchno doesn't work with UPDATE

```
UPDATE #test set total= (select count(batchno)as total from #test where (number=1 or number=3) and DayNo=1)

select * from #test
drop table #test
```

I keep getting this for a result

```
  batchno | Q | number | DayNo | total
   2        A     1      1        7
   2        A     1      1        7
   8        A     3      1        7
   8        A     3      1        7
   99       A     4      1        7
  200       A     3      1        7
  200       A     3      1        7
  200       A     3      1        7
```

I want to get something that looks like this when I use "SELECT * FROM #test"

```
  batchno | Q | number | DayNo | total
   2        A     1      1        2
   2        A     1      1        2
   8        A     3      1        2
   8        A     3      1        2
   99       A     4      1        null
  200       A     3      1        3
  200       A     3      1        3
  200       A     3      1        3
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using?  "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
UPDATE #test
    set total = (select count(batchno)as total
                 from #test t2
                 where t2.batchno = t.batchno and (number=1 or number=3) and DayNo=1)
    from #test t;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are very close, just use a temptable keeping the counts for each BatchNo and use it. Please try this:

```
select BatchNo,count(*) as total 
into #temp
from #test t1 
where (number=1 or number=3) and DayNo=1
Group by BatchNo 

UPDATE #test 
set total= (select total
            from #temp t
            where t.BatchNo = #test.BatchNo)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use window function instead:

```
select t.*, count(*) over(partition by batchno) as total 
from   #test
```

Answer (score -1):

In your subquery for apply the update on the set, your condition is setting all the values equal to that subquery. You may want to consider a where clause on the update OR utilizing a CTE that you can join back against the table.

```
;with cte as (
  select count(batchno)as total --this will be sigma of all batchno, my bad...
  from @test 
  where (number=1 or number=3) and DayNo=1
)
update @test
set total = (select total from cte)
where (number=1 or number=3) and DayNo=1
```